# Trying to create UDEV rule to mount removable drive exfat partition

Tags: mount, udev, exfat

So I am trying to create a udev rule to automatically mount a drives exfat partition to /media/offsite.  My goal is to automatically mount a drive to /media/offsite and then kick off a .sh script to copy files around.  I have been reading many guides and have learned a lot, but I am still getting stuck.  Many of the guides are very outdated and apply to USB drives where as I have a docked drive.

Just to see if a rule would trigger, I created this rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/80-external-disk.rules:

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="5359-818E", RUN+="/bin/mount -t exfat -U $env{ID_FS_UUID}"
```

I reloaded rules, rebooted server, few other things, and it appeared the rule wasn't firing.

```
udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb) 2>&1 | grep /etc/udev/rules.d
```

That only produces the following;

```
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/80-external-disk.rules' as rules file
```

My thought is that the UUID belongs to the partition and not the drive.  With the partition being an exfat, can UDEV even see that UUID?

Comment: With some help from Jordan_U in IRC, I have determined the disk does show up in /dev/disk/5359-818E.  Its just not getting that rule applied to it.

Comment: Check pluging the disk while running `sudo udevadm monitor -u` in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`mount` is not allowed in the late releases of udev. Better to go with udisks if you are using Gnome/Unity or any other alternative for other DE.

`man udev`

> **RUN**
>
> Note that running programs that access the network or mount/unmount
>   filesystems is not    allowed inside of udev rules, due to the default
>   sandbox that is enforced on    systemd-udevd.service.