# Udev correctly executes but usb stick won't automount since Ubuntu 16.04 and after

Tags: usb, mount, 18.04, automount, udev

I have been running Ubuntu 14.04 until I installed 18.04. On 14.04 I successfully created a udev rule that upon certain USB stick insertion it run a script AND the system used to auto-mount the stick (udev rules did not automount the stick).

But on 18.04 (and 16.04) when I insert the USB stick, the script successfully runs but the system will not auto-mount it. Please bear in mind that if I insert the stick on a different USB port (that is out of udev rule) then the system auto-mounts it.

Could it be that the udev inhibits the system somehow to auto-mount the usb stick? what has changed?

Thank you!

-----UPDATE UBUNTU 20.04-----

The aforementioned problem is solved. I don't know what changed, but in ubuntu 20.04 the automount of a usb stick HAPPENS, when a udev rule is triggered by it.
Still, for encyclopedic reasons, I leave this problem open for future suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Sorry my friend, that not allowed any more :) https://askubuntu.com/a/1181640/26246 , please if that the answer you want, let me know so i copy it here and vote to close or delete the other one.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it didn't mount with udisksctl either. I had tried it on 16.04, but not on the 18.04.